# software developed in vb.net hanging and it is giving exceptions

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

software developed in vb.net(communicating with serialport) hanging and it is giving these rexceptions

1.The device does not recognize the command

2.Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. if you click Quit, the application will close immediatly.   The device does not recognize the command..

Comment: Try to contact the **vendor** or **developer** who had developed that software.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is incomplete. Please provide your code and the serialport library you use.

If you use .NET 2.0 (and above) [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), the exception is clearer and it's more device independent as long as you are communicating over serial port. If you don't, then the exception isn't clear and can be too broad or too specific for specific devices.